# How to safely share ArrayDeque between multiple threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

Recently I started reading 'Java 7 Concurrency Cookbook' and in a section *Creating and running a daemon thread* found the code where main thread creates and one instance of `ArrayDeque` and shares its reference with three producers and one consumer. The producers call `deque.addFirst(event)` and the consumer calls `deque.getLast()`.

But JavaDoc of `ArrayDeque` clearly states that:

> Array deques are not thread-safe; in the absence of external synchronization, they do not support concurrent access by multiple threads.

So I wonder whether it is a mistake or I just don't understand something?

Comment: Looks like a mistake to me. It's not listed in the [errata](https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/support/10250), however.

Comment: It seems, the author saves talking about the necessity of synchronization for the second chapter. This might work for all other examples besides this one as they don’t share state, on the other hand, the entire first chapter, dealing with manual `Thread` handling, polling the status of threads in a loop, dealing with thread groups, etc. is more a chapter of the “and now forget everything you’ve read” kind…

Comment: @Holger Ok, I just wanted to make sure my understanding is correct.

Answer (score 2):

**Array deques are not thread safe, meaning you have to provide external synchronization.**

However why it works is, like holger said
[image: Deque methods]

You are using **addFirst(e)** is an insert model method which **does causes** change in underlying datastructure

You are using **getLast()** which is an examine model method which **does not causes** change in underlying datastructure.

That is why it is working, if you had used **removeLast()** instead of **getLast()**, you should have got **ConcurrentModification** **Exception** for sure.

Hope this clears up everything , Cheers

Answer (score -2):

It is clearly mentioned that if you are not going to provide any external synchronization, then ArrayDeque will not give you synchronization features just like Vector(provides internal features for thread safety-concurrency)